# question about CGAffineTransformTranslate

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, core-graphics

```
CGRect rect1 = backgroundImageView.frame;
NSLog(@"%f,%f,%f,%f",rect1.origin.x,rect1.origin.y,
                     rect1.size.width,rect1.size.height);

angle = -90.0;
moveX = 0;
moveY = 0.0;

CGFloat degreesToRadians = M_PI * angle / 180.0;
CGAffineTransform landscapeTransform =
      CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadians);
landscapeTransform =
      CGAffineTransformTranslate(landscapeTransform, moveX, moveY);
[backgroundImageView setTransform:landscapeTransform]; 

rect1 = backgroundImageView.frame;
NSLog(@"%f,%f,%f,%f",rect1.origin.x,rect1.origin.y,
                     rect1.size.width,rect1.size.height);
```

the debug message output:

```
0.000000,0.000000,320.000000,480.000000
-80.000000,80.000000,480.000000,320.000000
```

why does the (x,y) changes to (-80,80)?

Comment: Why are you translating the origin by zero points in each axis? That doesn't do anything. (Even if you think `CGAffineTransformTranslate` translates *to* that point, which it doesn't, that still wouldn't do anything: Translation moves the origin, and 0,0 *is* the origin, so translating to 0,0 would be moving the origin to the origin. That, too, would not do anything.)

Answer (score 0):

When you set the transform, the backgroundImageView.center does not change.  If the parent view has already rotated, yout can do something like this after applying the transform.

```
backgroundImageView.center = backgroundImageView.superview.center;
```

Either way, for your purposes you should adjust the center and not translate the transform.